# How can I set the background color of all cells in a table to red in LaTeX?

Tags: latex, overleaf

I'm trying to create a table in LaTeX where I want all cells to have a red background color. Here's an example of the table structure:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{RM - Realización de la memoria}} & \textbf{Primer prototipo 01/12/2022} & \\
& \textbf{Segundo prototipo 04/02/2023} & \textbf{X} \\
& \textbf{Entrega Final 15/03/2023} & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

I've tried using \cellcolor{red} and \columncolor{red} but only managed to color individual cells or half of the column. How can I set the entire column to have a red background color?

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to achieve this. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Have a look at the tabularray package - this makes it very easy to colour tables

Comment: i am using OverLeaf

Comment: That's ok. tabularay should be be available in the texlive 2022 version from overleaf